# Create an ID based on duplicates in google sheets using arrayformula

Tags: duplicates, numbers, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I need help to create an ID refer to data duplicates.

The reference column is A and the expected result is B.

Right now I use the following formula

```
=ArrayFormula(if(A2:A="";"";TEXT(COUNTIFS(A2:A;A2:A;ROW(A2:A);"<="&ROW(A2:A));"0#")))
```

and result in this (which I don't want this result)

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| A | 01 |
| B | 01 |
| C | 01 |
| B | 02 |
| D | 01 |
| A | 02 |
| B | 03 |
| D | 02 |
| E | 01 |

The result I really need is like this:

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| A | 01 |
| B | 02 |
| C | 03 |
| B | 02 |
| D | 04 |
| A | 01 |
| B | 02 |
| D | 04 |
| E | 05 |

Please help :(

Comment: The similar formula without arrayformula is like this:

=IF(A2="";"";IF(COUNTIF(A$1:A2;A2)>1;XLOOKUP(A2;A$1:A2;B$1:B2;"");max(B$1:B2)+1))

Answer (score 0):

*You may try:*

```js
=map(A2:A;lambda(Σ;if(Σ="";;if(countif(A2:Σ;Σ)=1;countunique(A2:Σ);
                               countunique(A2:index(A:A;xmatch(Σ;A:A)))))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much brother! It works
I just learn MAP and LAMBDA function from your post, it's interesting!
Thanks again!